# React destructuring rename

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

**Here's the goal**

From an app/module that has not been created with `create-react-app`

```
class Hoc extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {component: Component} = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <Component />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Description:**

Use basic ES6 destructuring with rename so that the react element can be referenced as `<Component />` instead of just a variable `{component}`.

I've been using this successfully in an app created from `create-react-app`. This syntax is documented in the [fullstack react](https://www.fullstackreact.com/) book. This issue is present in two react module libraries I'm working on that were not created from `create-react-app`.

The likely culprit is a missing babel plugin. The application this works in has been ejected so I can see all the dependencies and plugins, but I have not been able to identify one that works for this.

Hmmm, possibly it's handled by one of the react scripts that only come with `create-react-app`.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    "add-module-exports"
  ]
}
```

**Edit:**

This is a an example of the bare minimum requirements to exhibit the issue to be solved. Side step solutions like `this.props.children` and `{React.cloneElement(this.props.component, {...this.props})}` are not solutions to the specific issue. Cheers!

Comment: I think it's more of an anti-pattern to pass a component as a prop. If that component may change, you could just have a flag prop for which component it should be and then use regular imports for each possible component and use logic to render the correct one. Or if you're just passing it children, use `this.props.children`.

Comment: can you show your babel config?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a higher-order component (which is what I'm guessing, considering that you called your component `Hoc`), then you should follow the documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html.